# Is my keyboard "Generic 101-key PC" or "Generic 105-key PC (intl.)" or what?

Tags: xorg

How can I reliably and authoritatively determine which of the predefined "generic" X11 keyboard layouts is the best choice for my physical device? There must be a better way than counting keys and guessing whether it should be "intl" or not "intl".

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Mechanical.2C_visual_and_functional_layouts and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_keyboard#Keyboard_layouts ... honestly the best way (aside from assuming a particular default) is looking at the shape of the `Enter` and `Left Shift` keys and the number/position of modifier keys.  these are the "ANSI" and "ISO" layouts shown at the first link.

Comment: for XKB purposes, `intl` layouts are less about the actual hardware keyboard than about whether to include symbols on Level3 and Level5 (eg `AltGr`, deadkeys, etc).  when you load the basic US layout in XKB, it will not include any level3 or higher symbols, even if the physical keyboard is an "international" keyboard.  if you want `AltGr` and deadkeys and all the unicode goodies, you'll need an `intl` variant of the US layout.

Answer (score 8):

Most keyboards with a US layout are either 101-key or 104-key, depending on whether or not they have the two Meta/Super/Win keys and the Menu key. Standard "international" keyboard layouts are 102-key and 105-key.

If you're using a modern keyboard with a number pad and a US layout, it's most likely a 104-key.